# How to send a notification when website updates in Android?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am trying to write an application for Android that functions as a service in the background that will pop up a notification in the notification bar whenever a website is updated.  It is basically an RSS feed but as a service.

Any ideas on how best to do this?

******EDIT**********
This is a good example of the code that I was looking for which Mark Allison mentioned.
http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-03/msg03779.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this:

1. If you control the web server, you could post updates to registered apps using [CD2M](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html).
2. You write an Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which uses [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to wake it up periodically. Then you can use the HTTP [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) header to determine whether a page has changed without downloading it.
3. You do a hybrid of the two methods. You write a server which monitors a third-party website as per option 2, and then wakes your app using C2DM as per option 1.

Comment: I do not control the web server.  I knew that I would have some internal timer to periodically check.  Would alarm manager be the lowest memory profile way to do this, or are all methods equally memory intensive?

Will the page, if updated recently, for sure have the if-modified-since header?  I think you are saying that I would then need to read the html of the page and check for the mentioned header?

Comment: For best behaviour with AlarmManager, use the setInexactRepeating() method as it is much more battery friendly. When worken, you make a request to the server including the if-modified-since header. The  server should respond with a 304 (and no body data) if the content has not changed. If it has changed, then you'll get a 200 response and the new HTML in the body.

Comment: So I would need to use HttpClient and HttpGet to put the request into the server and then would I test my HttpClient for the 200 status?  Or could I test to see if it equals 304, under the assumption that if it doesn't it would equal 200 and there would be a change.  Do I pass in the if-modified-since-header to the HttpResponse call?

Comment: No, you would put the if-modified-since header in your HttpGet request and test the response to that. A status of 304 means nothing has changed.  You should not assume a 200 response if it's not a 304 because the transaction may have failed, and the response code will indicate why. If you get a 200 then the body of the response will contain the HTML, and you can then do whatever you need to with it.

Comment: This example is what I am looking for:  http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/http-webdav-sect-cond-get Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @ihtkwot: the link is dead, can you please upload the project, or if there is other link. Thank you very much.

Comment: i understand that the OP asked about how to do it, but i think a sample app could help develop a more efficient one. i found one such app , here it is -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.webalert