# Notify android app regarding content changes in the server

Tags: android, push-notification

Prior to posting this query here, I have gone through a similar requirement by a user in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447911/android-notify-android-phone-from-server)

Based on research, what I understand is, push notification concept can be used to notify the application of any changes happening in the server, if and only if, the server control rests with us.

I have made an application which would display the data from a mobile website. Is there a way out by which I can notify the handset user of any change happening in the server, such that the user gets an alert in his handset, so that he can open the application and see what is the new addition/change that has occurred in the website, when I have no control over the server? Pardon me , if I sound totally dumb with this question.  Had such a requirement and was curious to know the way out, if any.

Comment: You're looking for [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have read it though, before posting here. "Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device." It enables to send data from your server is what it says. In my case, the server control is not with me, as I have stated in my question.

Comment: You'll need your own server to monitor the website and then send a message via GCM as appropriate.

Comment: does that mean I can monitor only my websites (ie; websites I have hosted in servers like godaddy etc. which I have control over) . Or can I monitor the data changes happening to any general websites, blogs etc whose ownership does not rely on me?

Comment: a reverse approach is also feasible, the client side checking for changes on the serverside, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294147/how-to-send-a-notification-when-website-updates-in-android

Answer (score 1):

This way you should build your own web service which will poll other service for changing and then push alert to android device via Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM).

But you also can poll this service with your own application in background service. This method is very bad because of battery drain and network connection using, but this is no need for 3rd party services

Answer (score -1):

try noczone.com, they have custom notification service with an easy to use PHP sdk
https://noczone.com/?page=custom_alerts_sdk
i use it to let me know whenever i receive a support ticket or any new registrations.
and you will need to have their app installed to receive notifications on it
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wr.noc